# Access 2007 Query: Changing query to include column years instead of columns for this and last year

Tags: time

I am editing a database in `Access 2007`. Before, the database had `Columns`: 
`"Stocks Under Cover This Year"` and `"Stocks Under Cover Last Year."` For example,

*Stocks Under Cover This Year*: **3**

*Stocks Under Cover Last Year*: **2**

I have changed the `table` to instead have a "Year" column. For example,

*Year:* **2012**, *Stocks Under Cover*: **2**

*Year:* **2013**, *Stocks Under Cover*: **3**

My question is, before I had the query: `Analyst Data.Stocks Under Cover This Year`, how can I change it to fit my current table with `Years` instead? What if I need the query for each year, do I need to make `multiple columns` in the query or the same column with `multiple year` conditions?

I need to put this on a `form` where it says,

*Stocks Under Cover Last Year*: **2**

*Stocks Under Cover This Year*: **3**

Please advise.

**EDIT**:
To add one more example,

In the same query I need to know the Previous Year's 4q Rank and Current Year's 4q Rank.

Old `Table`:

```
Stocks_Under_Cover_Last_Year Stocks_Under_Cover_This_Year Rank_Previous_Year Rank_Current_Year
        2                                3                        32               31
```

New `Table`:

```
Year Stocks_Under_Cover Rank
2012        2            31               
2013        3            30
```

But I need the new query to fill out a form with Previous_Year_Rank: ... etc.

Same `form` format:

```
Stocks_Under_Cover_Last_Year Stocks_Under_Cover_This_Year Rank_Previous_Year Rank_Current_Year
        2                                3                        32               31
```

**EDIT 2:** So I think my solution is to use multiple queries in one form. The first query will query year 2012 and place the selected values into the fields in the form. The second query will query year 2013 and place the selected values in the fields in the form. I don't know how to make a form from multiple queries though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is a poor design to you use actual `Field Values` as `Field Names`. So, the best thing is to change the `Field Names` to a more sensible ones and store the appropriate values, that is, instead of `Year2012` or `Year2012` as `Field Names` you might change it to a more generic yet descriptive field name like `YearStockCovered` with the values on this field are the Years like `2012` or `2013` instead.

So, that you could easily query this tables like:

```
SELECT YearStockCovered, COUNT(*) as StockCount 
FROM StockTable
GROUP BY YearStockCovered
```

You might consider studying also `Normalization` on this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-rdbms-concepts.htm) (look at the bottom most).
This is very basic in achieving a more sensible `Database Design`.

Comment: I think I didn't type it out clearly. I am attempting to use normalization here. That's the whole change I need to implement. I meant Year COLUMN with VALUES 2012, 2013, etc etc. In the form it says Previous_Year_Rank: 30 but in the tables it's 2012, 30 as Values